# Having different table prefixes in separate Symfony2 Bundles

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, prefix

I've currently two separate bundles, one to authenticate incoming connections using oauth2, an another bundle to manage the api/rest calls.

I would like that the different tables associated to each bundle could have their own prefix according to the bundle. For instance having oauth_ for the first bundle and api_ for the other one.

Both services config files are correct (I guess), each of one specifies a different prefix:

```
<parameter key="MYBUNDLE.db.table_prefix" type="string" >oauth_</parameter>
```

and

```
<parameter key="MYBUNDLE.db.table_prefix" type="string" >api_</parameter>
```

Each bundle has also its service entry:

```
<service id="MYBUNDLE.tblprefix_subscriber" class="MYBUNDLE\Subscriber\TablePrefixSubscriber">
    <argument>%MYBUNDLE.db.table_prefix%</argument>
    <tag name="doctrine.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

and

```
<service id="MYBUNDLE.tblprefix_subscriber" class="MYBUNDLE\Subscriber\TablePrefixSubscriber">
    <argument>%MYBUNDLE.db.table_prefix%</argument>
    <tag name="doctrine.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

But if I execute the console command to create/update doctrine schema, it just uses ***api_*** prefix, but no oauth, for all the tables.

The subscriber looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace MYBUNDLE\Subscriber;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class TablePrefixSubscriber implements \Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber
{
    protected $prefix = '';

    public function __construct($prefix)
    {
        $this->prefix = (string) $prefix;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array('loadClassMetadata');
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args)
    {
        $classMetadata = $args->getClassMetadata();

        // Do not re-apply the prefix in an inheritance hierarchy.
        if ($classMetadata->isInheritanceTypeSingleTable() && !$classMetadata->isRootEntity()) {
            return;
        }

        if (FALSE !== strpos($classMetadata->namespace, 'ApiBundle') || FALSE !== strpos($classMetadata->namespace, 'AuthBundle')) {
            $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => $this->prefix . $classMetadata->getTableName()));

            foreach ($classMetadata->getAssociationMappings() as $fieldName => $mapping) {
                if ($mapping['type'] == \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::MANY_TO_MANY
                  && isset($classMetadata->associationMappings[$fieldName]['joinTable']['name'])) {
                    $mappedTableName = $classMetadata->associationMappings[$fieldName]['joinTable']['name'];
                    $classMetadata->associationMappings[$fieldName]['joinTable']['name'] = $this->prefix . $mappedTableName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, is it possible to have different prefixes? I thought it was possible but I am able to do it...

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that both prefixes share the same parameter key, with the second occurence overwriting the first.
I guess you must use two keys, like MYBUNDLE.db.table_prefix_oauth and MYBUNDLE.db.table_prefix_api.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.  Besides that I am using different TablePrefix Subscribers for each of the services. I don't know any other way to set different table prefixes.